# Print in VB 2010 is working but page missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, printing

I'm trying to print my form which I created with Visual Studio. I'm using power pack printing. All goes really well but I'm missing 2cm on the right side of my printout. Page on printer is set to A4.

This is what i try to do but no luck:

```
PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly)
```

Whatever I change, it is always printing the cropped page. I'm using xps printer at the moment and there is no zoom option. Can I set the form to zoom to fit the page?

The borders are also too big. Thats why my printout gets cropped, but I have no idea how to change it.

The size of my form is 711 x 1034 pixels, it's a desktop application.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3):

Ok finally find it :D probably too tired yesterday :D

If anyone need to change margin on printer here it is!!!

Code:

```
    PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)

    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPrinter

    PrintForm1.Print()
```